# Optimize heavy BigQuery DELETE query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, sql-optimization

The following BigQuery `DELETE` query fails by a timeout, because it reaches the limit of *6 hours* of execution time:

```sql
DELETE animals A WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT id from pets P WHERE A.id = P.id)
```

Table animals has ~50.000.000.000 records.
Table pets has ~300.000 records.

Tables are not partitioned.

Edit:
Seems like this query does not give any improvement:

```sql
DELETE animals WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id from pets)
```

Comment: I would recommend that you use a SELECT query which gets the unique records from `animals` and does a union with `pets` and writes into a new table. The truncate and load the data back into the original `animals` table.

Comment: Just to confirm, that's 50 billion rows, correct? @ElliottBrossard - any idea why this isn't scaling? Seems straightforward enough..

Comment: @GrahamPolley That's correct, 50 billion rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM(
  SELECT id, tbl, DENSE_RANK OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY tbl) AS rk FROM (
    SELECT id, 1 AS tbl FROM animals
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 0 AS tbl FROM pets)
  )
) WHERE rk = 1 AND tbl = 1;
```

This code will give you all the ids from animals which do not exist in pets.

If id is unique in animals you can use ROW_NUMBER() instead of DENSE_RANK().

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP was initially asking, was it?

Comment: I do really need to modify animals table daily, so would be better to find solution to quickly mutate it. I supposed it's irrelevant for BigQuery the number of rows, because of its scalability.